# How to pass the values to other function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to do this using VB.NET

I want to use a function in my codes like the following:

```
'Read all the content from the text file - Function One
'Write to SQL Table - Function Two
```

I am reading content of the text file form the Function one, but I also want to pass the values to function two.

I have more than 25 parameters of passing from function one to function two.

It is a simple question. Anyone can help to solve this issue.

Comment: You could use a class with 25 properties, then you only need to pass one instance of it to the method.

Comment: can you provide some samble example

Comment: Personally I would change the format of your text file to csv, read that into an array or list, then call the other function whilst passing the array as a parameter. Please could you post a section of the text file so I can give a solution.

Comment: Make a class that contains 25 different variables when you read those contents from file put them into Class variable (that contain 25 different variables) Now pass that variable to Function#2 that will update your SQL Table,

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to read the file in.

Comment: Just as they said, anytime, when you have more then 10 parameters - use a class that aggregates them ans pass it as one parameter

Answer (score 2):

You haven't give any sample so it's hard to help. You should definitely learn how to use classes. Group your variable together that have the same context.

```
Class Student
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    ' ...
End Class
```

When loading your data, you put it in an object.

```
Dim student As New Student

student.Age = 20
student.Name = "Bob"
```

After that you just need to pass the class as parameter to your function

```
Func(student)

Sub Func(ByVal student As Student)

End Sub
```